# Counting frequencies of array using object Sample Input ["a1", "b1","a2","a1", "b2", "b1"]; loop on object

Tags: javascript

Counting frequencies of array using object
Sample Input ["a1", "b1","a2","a1", "b2", "b1"];
Output: a1 - 2, b1- 2, a2- 1, b2 -1
looping should be done on object

im expecting loop on object

Comment: keep an empty object. loop the array. if the object doesnt have an array element as a key set a key with value 0. then increment that value

Comment: what have you tried, please post the code

Comment: var arr= ["a1","b1","a2","a1","b1","b2"];
const count = {};
 
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var num = arr[i];
    for (j=6;j<=num;j++)
    if (count[num]) {
        count[num] += 1;
    } else {
        count[num] = 1;
    }
}
console.log(count);

Comment: but i want a easy loop for counts that is here object

Comment: Why `for (j=6;j<=num;j++)`? That part doesn't make sense. The rest looks fine.

Comment: sorry wrong paste. i want to loop through the count(object) iam finding difficulty

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and put the code inside it, not in comments. Take a look here:  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)